# VBA-Excel How to clear ComboBox Items

Tags: excel, vba

i have a ComboBox with 3 items as "Select","Jack" and "Jill". Under **Private Sub Workbook_Open()** I kept the following lines of code.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1
    Items.Clear
    .AddItem "Select"
    .AddItem "Jack"
    .AddItem "Jill"
End With
```

When ever  i select an item and close the excel. Next time if i open the excel by default comboBox showing the previously selected item. But i want to show **select** as a default item.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to remove `Items.Clear` should be just `.Clear` and then use `.SelText` property to set the selected text

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1
    .Clear
    .AddItem "Select"
    .AddItem "Jack"
    .AddItem "Jill"
    .SelText = "Select"
End With
```