# Run-time error '424': Object required vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a combobox in worksheet. After I execute the subroutine `cmdUpdateDropDowns()`, there is a pop up error message saying "Object required" Run-time error '424'. This occurs in line 5 (`cmbKeyMetrics.Clear`). I am not sure how to define combobox in worksheet. I have named range it `cmbKeyMetrics`

```
Public Sub cmdUpdateDropDowns()

    strSQL = "Select Distinct [Key Metrics] From [data$] Order by [Key Metrics]"
    closeRS
    OpenDB
    cmbKeyMetrics.Clear

    rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            cmbKeyMetrics.AddItem rs.Fields(0)
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "No key metrics available.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I think named ranges must be look like

```
Range("cmbKeyMetrics").clear
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear your combobox, you need to add a worksheet reference.
`Worksheets("NameOfYourWorksheet").cmbKeyMetrics.Clear`

See related question on [SO-VBA-Excel How to clear ComboBox Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209383/vba-excel-how-to-clear-combobox-items)